How do I fix this wobbly faucet?
I have a wobbly sink faucet. This is a video of what happens when I wobble it, above and below.



Clearly something is missing, but I just don't know what. What do I need to buy and install to fix this?

Does the bottom rotate to tighten/loosen the connection?

There seems to be a nut on a bolt/stud between the two hoses.  Have you tried to tighten it?

Turn the brass barrel nut clockwise as you are looking at it. (blue line)
That will tighten the faucet.  There is water leaking around the base and degrading the counter.  Before you tighten you may want to loosen the assembly and seal the base of the faucet to the counter with plumbers putty.


To be clear, I need some kind of wrench to turn the actual brass thing - not the flathead nut inside it? I tried using a flathead screwdriver to tighten the silver thing inside the brass tube, but nothing much happened. Also, could you be a little more specific about where I should apply putty?

@Jack M,  Apply putty to the underside of the faucet between the faucet and countertop..  The screw that you are trying to turn is already tightened to the faucet. You cannot turn it to tighten anything.  It is a threaded rod that the barrel nut threads to. You must tighten the barrel nut. Use an open end wrench, or better  a socket and socket wrench that will fit over the nut.  I'm guessing it is a 1/2 inch or maybe 13mm.

Thanks. Are you recommending putty purely to prevent further damage, or are you saying that the reason the faucet may be loose is because it's having trouble gripping the damaged surface, and the putty will give it more purchase?

Putty can help prevent further damage. The damage ( crumbling particle board),on the underside of the counter is what has made the faucet loose.
